# iOS - App Store Connect / App Analytics shows unnatural deletion spikes

Tags: app-store-connect

I just looked the "Deletions" tab on App Store Connect/App Analytics and saw 4 high and unnatural spikes, 3 from US and 1 from UK. Also highest spike comes from only iPad devices. I looked at the "installation" and "crashes" data and there is not any anomaly there.

One thing that comes to my mind is that Apple counts installation of the development builds as deletion. Because it overwrites the previous build. But this doesn't explain the spike on UK Store since my devices are not connected to UK store.

Anyone saw similar thing? Is that a bug of App Store?

[image: Deletion spikes]

Comment: Any updates? I've been dealing with the same confusion over massive deletion spikes in my own analytics reports

Answer (score 1):

By default your app would be on the App Store in all regions(which the UK is included) unless you specifically region locked your app. Someone in the UK or at least connected to the the UK region store(they can be in that region but outside of the region physically) can still download your app, when I launched my app it took me awhile to find information on this. If your app is free you are probably more likely to have more downloads worldwide, but with it being free people will also delete it to clear up space. It is not uncommon to have high spikes around a release of a big app of the same content, I usually see this as a sign I need to reevaluate how I am retaining users. Apps sometimes need to be deleted to allow for updates to the IOS to be installed which will also cause you to see spikes at certain times, but you should also compare your crash data(if you have any crashes) to see if it aligns with the deletion of your app, since some people will report it but not describe the crash and I don't know a lot of people who keep apps that crash on their phones.

Comment: There is no crashes at around the deletion spikes. My devices are on US Store, so I thought I may be the cause of the US deletion spikes during development. My hypothesis is that Apple counts overwriting on the old build as a  deletion. But UK is a different story.

Comment: 2 out of 4 spikes occur at the date of the app update. Do you know that iOS automatically deletes the app before updating the app itself?

Comment: I would say no, since when I look at my deletions they do not align with the app updates. I can also verify as some of my coworkers use my app and update it as soon as I push updates.